# Get image from response

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've made a class (Draw.aspx) that generates bitmap and returns it in request response:

```
    Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
```

Everything works good, when i run Draw.aspx in my web browser it shows generated image, i can save it on my hard drive, etc...

Now I wanted to call this request from another site (~/default.aspx), and from there save this image to server (ex. image.png) or use it in website. I tried to run this code, but the problem is i get .html part of Draw.aspx instead of just .png:

```
    String inputImage = Server.MapPath("Draw.aspx");
    String outputImage = Server.MapPath("image.png");

    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(inputImage);
    WebRequest.Create(inputImage);

    webRequest.Method = "GET";
    webRequest.ContentType = "image/png; encoding='utf-8'";

    WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

    StreamReader oReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    StreamWriter oWriter = new StreamWriter(outputImage);

    oWriter.Write(oReader.ReadToEnd());
```

What image.png file contains (instead of actual image):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Draw.aspx.cs" Inherits="Draw" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've been trying to solve this problem for couple of hours but nothing seems to work right and I think that I might've misunderstood how requesting a response works.

I'd really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to download an image, so use an image object!

ImageFeeder.ashx (note: this is just what I called my file that spits out the image.  Rename accordingly):

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="ImageFeeder" %>

using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

public class ImageFeeder : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.BufferOutput = true;

        MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
        Image i = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Path\to\image.PNG");
        i.Save(m, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        context.Response.BinaryWrite(m.ToArray());
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your other page, just use an image object.  For example, starting with the default aspx form page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Create an image in the codebehind and do whatever you want with it.  for example:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image i = new Image();
        i.ImageUrl = "ImageFeeder.ashx";
        // Now do whatever you want with it.
        form1.Controls.Add(i);

    }
}
```

The Image will be inserted AFTER the div that is inside the form tag.  Since it's an image object, you can do whatever you want with it...display it, save it, etc.

It's that easy!

**EDIT:**
Saving the image is slightly more difficult, but not very.  First, you will need a `WebClient` object, then download the file using A: the complete url to your image feeder, and B: the absolute path of where you want to save things.  Let's assume you're running on localhost on a special port (like when you dev things in VS), and you want to dump the image in the same directory as everything else.  You'd end up with this in the codebehind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadFile("http://localhost:61579/ImageFeeder.ashx", Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("."), "myimage.png"));
    }
}
```

Obviously you need all of your `using` statements as well.

Comment: Thank You for response. I was using similar code before but I gave up on it because I wanted to have control over generated image and in this example it's directly linked to Image (control). What could i possibly do if, for example i wanted to show it on site **and** save it on server?

Comment: updated the answer.  To both show it and save it, simply combine the two methods I have provided.

Comment: Your answer was really helpfull! I'll read a little bit more about classes and methods that you used because though they work I have some questions about how :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)  Good luck with your project!

Comment: "Image i = new Image();" is not correct and should instead be "Image i = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs);"